# Async recursive using promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise

So i am trying to transfer my code into the "Promise world", and in many places when i had to "loop" with async functionality - i simply used recursion in such a way

```
function doRecursion(idx,callback){
    if(idx < someArray.length){
        doAsync(function(){
            doRecursion(++idx,callback)
        });
    }else{
        callback('done!')
    }
}
doRecursion(0,function(msg){
    //...
});
```

Now i am trying to make the change into the Promise world, and i am quite stuck

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
function doRecursion(idx){
    return new Promise(function(resolve){
        if(idx < someArray.length){
            doAsync(function(){
                //... doRecursion(++idx)
                // how do i call doRecusion here....
            });
        }else{
            resolve('done!')
        }
    });
}
doRecursion(0).then(function(msg){
    //...
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: `resolve(doRecursion(++idx));` - if you resolve Promise 1 with Promise 2, then Promise 1 will resolve with the resolved value of Promise 2

Comment: Please stop using the [promise constructor anti-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/918910). This goes for the answers too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with the `Promise.all` approach.

What this does is wait until all the promises in the array have resolved. The map will apply the async method to each item in the array and return a promise.

```
function doAsyncP() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        doAsync(function() {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}

Promise.all(
    someArray.map(doAsyncP)
).then((msg) => {
    //we're done.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your recursive function, you can do this:

```
...
if (idx < someArray.length) {
  doAsync(function() {
    resolve(doRecursion(idx + 1));
   });
} else {
...
```

In other words, while `idx` is less than `someArray.length`, your promise will resolve to another promise, this time the promise returned by calling `doRecursion()` with an `idx` incremented by one. The `then` callback the bottom will not be called until `doRecursion` resolves to some value other than a promise. In this case, it will eventually resolve with a value of `'done!'`.

That said, if you are using promises, you probably don't need to use recursion at all. You might have to refactor your code a bit more, but I would suggest considering @BenFortune's answer as an alternative.

Comment: Bit of an anti-pattern IMO if you're using promises.

Comment: @BenFortune Yes, I agree, but it's what the asker asked. I've never even thought about using recursion with promises before, and that is probably why. The asker should consider your accepting your answer instead.